zookeeper not working, getting following error on mac
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,000] INFO Server environment:java.library.path=/Users/vookar/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,000] INFO Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/c2/r8lbs0qd59q0fnpjg1zxvx340000gq/T/ (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,000] INFO Server environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,000] INFO Server environment:os.name=Mac OS X (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,000] INFO Server environment:os.arch=x86_64 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,000] INFO Server environment:os.version=14.4 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,000] INFO Server environment:user.name=vookar (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,000] INFO Server environment:user.home=/Users/vookar (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,000] INFO Server environment:user.dir=/Users/vookar (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,000] INFO Server environment:os.memory.free=488MB (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,001] INFO Server environment:os.memory.max=512MB (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,001] INFO Server environment:os.memory.total=512MB (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,001] INFO zookeeper.enableEagerACLCheck = false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,001] INFO zookeeper.digest.enabled = true (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,001] INFO zookeeper.closeSessionTxn.enabled = true (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,001] INFO zookeeper.flushDelay = 0 ms (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,001] INFO zookeeper.maxWriteQueuePollTime = 0 ms (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,001] INFO zookeeper.maxBatchSize=1000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,001] INFO zookeeper.intBufferStartingSizeBytes = 1024 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,002] INFO Weighed connection throttling is disabled (org.apache.zookeeper.server.BlueThrottle)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,004] INFO minSessionTimeout set to 6000 ms (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,004] INFO maxSessionTimeout set to 60000 ms (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,004] INFO getData response cache size is initialized with value 400. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ResponseCache)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,004] INFO getChildren response cache size is initialized with value 400. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ResponseCache)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,005] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.slotCapacity = 60 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,005] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.slotDuration = 15 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,005] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.maxDepth = 6 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,005] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.initialDelay = 5 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,005] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.delay = 5 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,005] INFO zookeeper.pathStats.enabled = false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.util.RequestPathMetricsCollector)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,008] INFO The max bytes for all large requests are set to 104857600 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,009] INFO The large request threshold is set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,009] INFO zookeeper.enforce.auth.enabled = false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.AuthenticationHelper)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,009] INFO zookeeper.enforce.auth.schemes = [] (org.apache.zookeeper.server.AuthenticationHelper)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,009] INFO Created server with tickTime 3000 ms minSessionTimeout 6000 ms maxSessionTimeout 60000 ms clientPortListenBacklog -1 datadir /tmp/zookeeper/version-2 snapdir /tmp/zookeeper/version-2 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,020] INFO Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,021] WARN maxCnxns is not configured, using default value 0. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,022] INFO Configuring NIO connection handler with 10s sessionless connection timeout, 2 selector thread(s), 24 worker threads, and 64 kB direct buffers. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,060] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,080] INFO Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.watch.WatchManager as watch manager (org.apache.zookeeper.server.watch.WatchManagerFactory)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,080] INFO Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.watch.WatchManager as watch manager (org.apache.zookeeper.server.watch.WatchManagerFactory)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,081] INFO zookeeper.snapshotSizeFactor = 0.33 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,081] INFO zookeeper.commitLogCount=500 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,086] INFO zookeeper.snapshot.compression.method = CHECKED (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.SnapStream)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,107] ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
java.io.IOException: No snapshot found, but there are log entries. Something is broken!
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:290)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.loadDataBase(ZKDatabase.java:285)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.loadData(ZooKeeperServer.java:531)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.startdata(ZooKeeperServer.java:704)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.startup(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:744)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory.startup(ServerCnxnFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:161)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:113)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:68)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:141)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:91)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,112] INFO ZooKeeper audit is disabled. (org.apache.zookeeper.audit.ZKAuditProvider)
[2024-04-29 19:15:20,115] ERROR Exiting JVM with code 1 (org.apache.zookeeper.util.ServiceUtils)

trying to start Zookeeper :
zookeeper-server-start.sh /Users/xxxxx/kafka_2.13-3.7.0/config/zookeeper.properties


Does this answer your question? Zookeeper: java.io.IOException: No snapshot found, but there are log entries. Something is broken
